# how to create a chess board with Queen in the central position and all its moves in assembler code

Tags: cassandra

section data is where I get the error
section data
queen_row db 4  ; Fila inicial de la Reina
queen_col db 4  ; Columna inicial de la Reina
timer_ticks db 0 ; Contador de ticks del temporizador

section .text
global _start

_start:
; Configurar temporizador
mov al, 0B6h  ; Modo 3 del temporizador (modo binario)
out 43h, al   ; Envía el comando al controlador del temporizador
mov ax, 1193h ; Valor inicial del temporizador para 10ms
out 40h, al   ; Envía el byte menos significativo
mov al, ah
out 40h, al   ; Envía el byte más significativo

timer_loop:
mov al, 0 ; Esperar a que el temporizador alcance su intervalo
in al, 61h     ; Leer el registro del controlador del teclado
test al, 1     ; Verificar si el bit 0 está activo (indicando que se ha producido un tick)
jz timer_loop  ; Si no se ha producido un tick, esperar

```
inc byte [timer_ticks] ; Incrementar contador de ticks


 cmp byte [timer_ticks], 5
jne timer_loop; Mover la Reina a una nueva posición cada 5 ticks

; Mover la Reina a una nueva posición en el tablero (aquí iría tu lógica de movimiento)

; Reiniciar el contador de ticks
mov byte [timer_ticks], 0

jmp timer_loop ; Volver a esperar al próximo tick del temporizador
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with [tag:cassandra]? Also, your code and error message looks like important context but they are not in English. Please provide English translation/equivalent as StackOverflow is an English-only site.